# Font rendering misalignment , Font rendering differences on Puppeteer, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

It is normal for me to access the page through Chrome, but there is a problem with text formatting when accessing the app. I suspect it is caused by a launch parameter. Please help me.

**correct：**
[correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhSdL.png)

**wrong**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adTgp.png)

My code

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-gpu',
        "--proxy-server='direct://'",
        '--proxy-bypass-list=*',
        '--allow-file-access-from-files',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--no-first-run',
        '--no-zygote',
        '--font-render-hinting=none',
    ],
});
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('https://www.***.com');
```

I removed --font-render-hinting, it does not take effect

Comment: text height is different

Comment: This seems like a design/CSS problem in the website you're automating. You can maybe cover it up with Puppeteer settings (try changing the viewport?), but properly coded websites shouldn't break like this on any settings. It's difficult to guess what the problem/solution might be without access to the site itself, or a minimal reproduction of the problematic behavior.